# "Cannot find module 'three' from"

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify

I'm having a hard time migrating my toy typescript app at http://ssrb.github.io/mega-structure/mega-structure.html from `typings` to `@types/npm`.

The error I can't figure out is `Error: Cannot find module 'three'`
and `Error: Cannot find module 'codemirror'`

The workflow is `typescript/gulp/browserify`.

For that migration, I deleted my `typings.json` as well as all the typing stuff from my `gulpfile` and `npm install @types`.

Then I fixed a few errors due to some API changes after upgrading the type definitions.

I replaced `///<reference path="typings/index.d.ts"/>` with some `import * as THREE from 'three';`

It now fails to bundle and I'm trying to figure it out without success:

```
[13:41:56] Using gulpfile mega-structure/gulpfile.js
[13:41:56] Starting 'default'...
[13:41:56] Starting '.bower.install'...
[13:41:58] Using cwd: mega-structure
[13:41:58] Using bower dir: ./bower_components
[13:42:01] Finished '.bower.install' after 4.99 s
[13:42:01] Starting '.peg'...
[13:42:01] Finished '.peg' after 131 ms
[13:42:01] Starting '.examples'...


[13:42:01] Finished '.examples' after 155 ms
[13:42:01] Starting '.ui.release'...
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'three' from 'mega-structure'
    at mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at mega-structure/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
```

See https://github.com/ssrb/mega-structure/commit/3285f5cb45c110d87ea5db795e47a4a392a15c1f and https://travis-ci.org/ssrb/mega-structure/builds/359637820?utm_source=email&utm_medium=notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the build was consuming type declarations for`three.js`, `codemirror`, ...  installed with `npm` but the matching `javascript` libraries were still installed using `bower`. 
After installing the libraries with `npm` rather than `bower` the build recovered.